# Umbraco Site Publishing

Tags: umbraco

I am using umbraco v 4.11.6 (Assembly version: 1.0.4834.19775) the issue is every time the server shuts down or restarts I need to republish the pages which are not loaded.
So please let me know the root cause for this issue if anyone knows or any other things that can be done to over come from this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid this question appears to be off-topic because it is about Umbraco usage rather than programming.

Answer (score 3):

In version 4.6 there was an issue which had the same behavior when the SQL database was not available at boot time of the website.  But with version 4.11 this should be fixed a long time.

I would investigate the logs (~/app_data/logs/).  You might find some clue there.  Append logs to your post if you can not find the issue.

This might be a problem with some `ApplicationEventHandlers` not running properly.  Or with write permissions on the proper folders.  Try adding more logs to the code, so you are sure what runs (and what doesn't).

If you can not find the answer, try the umbraco forums : http://our.umbraco.org/forum